# How to change my td button element from text to an image linked to url?

Tags: html

EDIT: I'm using Stratus soundcloud API so I don't want the url to lead me to another tab or page. It should just have sorta like a popup at the bottom of the page for the music to play. Sorry, should have written this in earlier!

I have this string that I am setting to my variable. Inside the string, I have a `td` element for a button called PlayButton that's linked to a url. Currently it's just a text "Play song" but I want to change this into an image (i.e. using "assets/play.png").

```
var track = '<tr><td><button class="playButton" data-url="'+url+'"><img src="assets/play.png" alt="Play Song"></button></td><td><button class="playlistButton"> + </button></td></tr>';
```

I want to do the same thing for the playlistButton so changing it from a text "+" sign to an image of a plus sign.

Thanks!

Comment: why dont u just use <a> tag, else you can just put <img> tag inside that button (replacing the "+")

Comment: You can add background-image for the button using css.

Comment: @kasnady can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `<a> </a>` tags.

Here:

```
var track = '
    <tr>
        <td>
         <a class="playButton" href="'+url+'"><img src="assets/play.png" alt="Play Song"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="playlistButton" href = "url"> + </a>
        </td>
    </tr>';
```

And for the new tab part use this

To open in a new tab:

```
var track = '
    <tr>
        <td>
         <a class="playButton" href="'+url+'" target="_blank"><img src="assets/play.png" alt="Play Song"></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="playlistButton" href = "url" target="_blank"> + </a>
        </td>
    </tr>';
```

To open in the same tab use this:

```
var track = '
        <tr>
            <td>
             <a class="playButton" href="'+url+'" target="_self"><img src="assets/play.png" alt="Play Song"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="playlistButton" href = "url" target="_self"> + </a>
            </td>
        </tr>';
```

Comment: Hi, I'm so sorry can you look at my question again? I realize that there was a crucial component of my question missing (i.e. not opening to a new tab). Also, because I'm new, I can only resolve the question but not upvote until I have enough of a reputation I believe.

Comment: Well, you just took away my ability to comment to your question. But lemme look for an answer. Plus you just edited your question.

Comment: Oh if I did I'm sorry I have no idea how I did that. I just unchecked the question and responded to your comment.

Comment: Hi, I have made the changes as requested. Please check it as the solution if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `button` to `a`

Example below.

```html
<tr><td><a class="playButton" href="'+url+'"><img src="assets/play.png" alt="Play Song"></a></td><td><a class="playlistButton" href="#"> + </a></td></tr>
```

Base

```
var track = '<tr><td><button class="playButton" data-url="'+url+'"><img src="assets/play.png" alt="Play Song"></button></td><td><button class="playlistButton"> + </button></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var track = '
<tr>
    <td>
     <a class="playButton" href="'+url+'" style="background-image:url("assets/play.png");background-repeat:no-repeat;" alt="Play Song"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a class="playlistButton" href = "'+url+'" style="background-image:url("assets/play.png")" > + </a>
    </td>
</tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a> </a>
```

tag. It is uses for hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to 
another. Try to go to this link ( https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp ) for more info about   tag.